# How do I alternate two Images in a react native component

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to animate an icon in React native by simply switching the image every 500ms. My code looks like this:

```
export default class FlashingIcon extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      on: true,
    };

    setInterval(() => {
       this.setState(previousState => {
         return {
           on: !previousState.on,
        };
      });
    }, 500);
  }

  render() {
    let sprite = this.state.on
      ? require('../onIcon.png')
      : require('../offIcon.png');

    return (
      <Image
        source={sprite}
        style={{width:16, height:20}}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

The code is basically copy-and-pasted from:

- https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state.html and
- https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html

Each image shows up if I just copy the `require` into the `<Image>`. I can also verify that if I instead render a `<Text>` element outputting `this.state.on`, it shows the correct value alternating.

I can't for the life of me work out what I've done wrong.

Comment: @JigarShah I'm not sure what you're trying to point out? I've omitted the imports for brevity, but they're there (the image does in fact render, it just doesn't toggle between the two provided images)

Comment: rather than assigning it to `let` you can directly add condition on `source`

Comment: @JigarShah that doesn't work either.

Comment: it works for me.  However, the image didn't show up until I made it way bigger.

Comment: try to increase Interval and also add `key={this.state.on}`

Comment: @RajSuvariya no errors - just the image not alternating. It shows a single, static image that doesn't toggle to the other image. If I use a `<Text>` element instead, I can see it flipping between `true` and `false`, but the `<Image>` doesn't flip.

Comment: @JigarShah why would increasing the interval do anything? And add `key` where?

Comment: @whs.bsmith did you use this exact code?

Comment: `export default class FlashingIcon extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      on: true,
    };

    setInterval(() => {
       this.setState(previousState => {
         return {
           on: !previousState.on,
        };
      });
    }, 500);
  }

  render() {
    let sprite = this.state.on
      ? require('./assets/12dark.png')
      : require('./assets/12eyes.png');

    return (
      <Image
        source={sprite}
        style={{width:200, height:20}}
      />
    );
  }
}`

Comment: key to `image` like this: `<Image key={this.state.on}`. It will help in re-rendering image once state changed.

Comment: @JigarShah YOU ARE A GENIUS - if you post it as an actual answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad to help you @Alec :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `key` to `Image`  It will help in re-rendering image once state changed.

```
<Image
    key={this.state.on}
    source={sprite}
    style={{width:16, height:20}}
  />
```

Comment: If anyone's curious about why this works, there's a very good overview here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html